# PHP - Nth Recursion how to convert a function to nth level without hard coding?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I like to see if there is a better way to write the following code ? with nth level and with no holes in the execution ?

```
public function getRequestBody($request_service, $request_model)
    {
        $request_operation = $request_service->request_code . $request_service->request_operation . 'Request';
        $request = '<ns1:' . $request_operation . '>';
        foreach (get_object_vars($request_model) as $property => $value) {
            if (!is_object($value)) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    foreach ($value as $property_arr) {
                        if (!is_object($property_arr)) {

                        } else {
                            $request .= '<ns1:' . $property . '>';
                            foreach (get_object_vars($property_arr) as $property_inner => $value_inner) {
                                if (is_array($value_inner)) {
                                    foreach ($value_inner as $property_arr_1) {
                                        if (!is_object($property_arr_1)) {

                                    } else {
                                        $request .= '<ns1:' . $property_inner . '>';
                                        foreach (get_object_vars($property_arr_1) as $property_inner_1 => $value_inner_1) {
                                            $request .= '<ns1:' . $property_inner_1 . '>' . $value_inner_1 . '</ns1:' . $property_inner_1 . '>';
                                        }
                                        $request .= '</ns1:' . $property_inner . '>';
                                    }
                                }

                            } else {
                                $request .= '<ns1:' . $property_inner . '>' . $value_inner . '</ns1:' . $property_inner . '>';
                            }
                        }
                        $request .= '</ns1:' . $property . '>';
                    }
                }

            } else {
                $request .= '<ns1:' . $property . '>' . $value . '</ns1:' . $property . '>';
            }
        } else {
            $request .= '<ns1:' . $property . '>';
            foreach (get_object_vars($value) as $property1 => $value1) {
                if (!is_object($value1)) {
                    $request .= '<ns1:' . $property1 . '>' . $value1 . '</ns1:' . $property1 . '>';
                } else {
                    $request .= '<ns1:' . $property1 . '>';
                    foreach (get_object_vars($value1) as $property_inner_2 => $value_inner_2) {
                        if (!is_object($value_inner_2)) {
                            $request .= '<ns1:' . $property_inner_2 . '>' . $value_inner_2 . '</ns1:' . $property_inner_2 . '>';
                        } else {
                            $request .= '<ns1:' . $property_inner_2 . '>';
                            foreach (get_object_vars($value_inner_2) as $property_inner_3 => $value_inner_3) {
                                if (!is_object($value_inner_3)) {
                                    $request .= '<ns1:' . $property_inner_3 . '>' . $value_inner_3 . '</ns1:' . $property_inner_3 . '>';
                                }
                            }
                            $request .= '</ns1:' . $property_inner_2 . '>';
                        }
                    }
                    $request .= '</ns1:' . $property1 . '>';
                }
            }
            $request .= '</ns1:' . $property . '>';
        }
    }
    $request .= '</ns1:' . $request_operation . '>';
    return $request;
}
```

Comment: please fix formatting

Comment: may belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah how can i move this ?

Comment: Current code is one big hole. Use a SOAP or at least an XML API.

Comment: If you use PHP's built-in SOAP client, you will not have to parse the XML at all, and this entire code block would be eliminated.  The point of SOAP is work with objects, and the XML is hidden and abstracted.